# store data from ajax source jquery data table in Knockout array

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I want to ask that how can i store the data received from ajaxsource jquery datatable in a knockout array.Let,me explain it with help of code:

```
 that.oDataTable = $('#KeysTable').dataTable({

            // to set server interaction to true
            "bServerSide": true,

            // to tell Data Table to enable processing mode ( enable loading indicator)
            "bProcessing": true,

            // using  column reorder plug-in
            "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',

            // to set up the URL to seek for JSON data
            "sAjaxSource": "/go/sampless/sample/",

            // to set the method for Ajax call
            "sServerMethod": "GET",

            // to enable Pagination
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

            // to save state where user has left (pagination, filter) :: to use this need to disable defer render
            "bStateSave": true,

            // allow defer Render mode. i.e. show total records  
            "bDeferRender": false,

            "sAjaxDataProp": "sampleData",

            // to change the text 
            "oLanguage": {
                // when no data is available at page load
                "sEmptyTable": "No records found",

                // remove the text 'Processing' while loading
                "sLoadingRecords": ""
            },


            ],
```

From this code i am successfully able to get data from server and populate it in html table 
Now what i want is that i want to store this data in KO array as example

```
that.KoData(sAjaxDataProp);
```

but by this approach i am unable to store it in KO array
actually i want to iterate through the value of data in array and use condition for displaying it 
for example i want to put a condition in data table on a cell
as

```
<td>
                                <!--ko if: ReworkCount-->
                                <label class="goto"><b data-bind="text: sample"></b>   </label>
                                <!--/ko-->
  </td>
```

actually i want to implement this sort of functionality in html page.If,some other solution using data table is also possible then would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly understand your question, but this maybe help.

```
that.myArray = ko.observableArray([]); // ko array

that.myArray.push(sAjaxDataProp); // insert data into ko array
```

Comment: this way i am unable to store data from ajax source